# Comparing items of two lists to scoop out the desired portion

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, conditional-statements

There are two lists- one contain `list of states` and the other contain `list of addresses`. What I'm trying to do is compare `each of the state` to `each of the address` in order to find if there is a match. When a match is found then the script should scoop out that portion from the addresses.

Here is what i did (working one):

```
state_list = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CO', 'CT', 'IL', 'MI']
addresses = ['Downers Grove IL 60515','Duarte CA 91010','Ann Arbor MI 48108']

for item in state_list:
    for address in addresses: 
        if item in address: 
            state = address
            print(state.split(" ")[-2])
```

Output:

```
IL
MI
```

***Can I do the same making one liner approach rather than this clumsy looking loop?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print([state for state in state_list
       if any(state in addr for addr in addresses)])
```

Output:

```
['IL', 'MI']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `regex` for this.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(state_list))

[pattern.search(address).group(0) for address in addresses if pattern.search(address)]

['IL', 'MI']
```

Or using higher order functions

```
[m.group(0) for m in filter(None, map(pattern.search, addresses))]

['IL', 'MI']
```